# Impossible to update textbox from another frame, how I can fix that?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm creating a small numeric keyboard like those on our smartphones, when I press a key, the digit must be written in a TextBox. 
This is where I have a problem, I can not update my TextBox when I press a button.

My window is decomposed into two frames of the same width, the keyboard is on the left frame and the TextBox on the right frame.

I call a method in my Clavier.xaml.cs page:

```
CallSection EtablissementAppel = new CallSection();

private void UpdateTextBox(string _UpdatePrefix, string _UpdateNumeroDestinataire)
{
    EtablissementAppel.UpdateEtablissementAppel(_UpdatePrefix, _UpdateNumeroDestinataire);
}
```

Method in the CallSection.xaml.cs file:

```
public void UpdateEtablissementAppel(string p, string n)
{
     string Numero = p + n;
     EtablissementAppel.Text = Numero;
}
```

Code CallSection.xaml :

```
<TextBox x:Name="EtablissementAppel" Margin="5,5,5,5" PlaceholderText="ETABLISSEMENT D'APPEL" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="37"/>
```

Yet the TextBox does not want to update itself. Knowing that I can change its text anywhere in the file CallSection.xaml.cs but not in this method.

EDIT :

To give more details in relation to the first comments.

Method in CallSection.xaml.cs with a Debug.WriteLine() :

```
public void UpdateEtablissementAppel(string p, string n)
{
    string Numero = p + n;
    Debug.WriteLine(Numero);
    EtablissementAppel.Text = Numero;
}
```

Here I can see in the debugger all my numbers tapped. But textbox doesn't update.

Debugger output :

```
12255
122552
1225525
12255255
122552555
```

CallSection.xaml :

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PhonieMartha"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Custom="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    x:Class="PhonieMartha.CallSection"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded" 
    >

    <Page.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GraySelected" Color="#FFA3A3A3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GrayUnselected" Color="#33000000"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Page.Background>
        <ThemeResource ResourceKey="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"/>
    </Page.Background>

    <Grid x:Name="GrillePrincipale">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="EtablissementAppel" Margin="5,5,5,5" PlaceholderText="ETABLISSEMENT D'APPEL" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="37"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Call1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#33000000" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFE03535" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Tapped="Call1_Tapped"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Call2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#33000000" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFE03535" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Tapped="Call2_Tapped"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Call3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#33000000" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFE03535" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Tapped="Call3_Tapped"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Call4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#33000000" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFE03535" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Tapped="Call4_Tapped"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Call5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#33000000" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFE03535" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Tapped="Call5_Tapped"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Call6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#33000000" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFE03535" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Tapped="Call6_Tapped"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Call7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#33000000" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFE03535" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Tapped="Call7_Tapped"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Call8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#33000000" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFE03535" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Tapped="Call8_Tapped"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="RenvoiAppel" Margin="5,5,5,5" PlaceholderText="RENVOI D'APPEL" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="37" Grid.Row="5" InputScope="Number"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="MessageRecu" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ToggleSwitch x:Name="ToggleSwitchRenvoiAppel" Margin="5,5,5,5" OnContent="On" OffContent="Off" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Toggled="ToggleSwitchRenvoiAppel_Toggled"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Row="5" Text="PhonieMartha                                   Rev1.0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="12"/>


    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is the XAML code of the MainPage that contains the two frames :

```
 <Page
    x:Class="PhonieMartha.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PhonieMartha"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="GrilleMainPage">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame x:Name="CallsSection" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <NavigationView x:Name="NavView" SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" PaneDisplayMode="Auto" CompactModeThresholdWidth="300" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="550" Grid.Column="0">

            <NavigationView.MenuItems>

                <NavigationViewItem Icon="PhoneBook" Content="Annuaire général" Tag="AnnuaireGeneral"/>

                <NavigationViewItem Icon="PhoneBook" Content="Annuaire personnel" Tag="AnnuairePersonnel"/>

                <NavigationViewItem Content="Clavier" Tag="Clavier">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <FontIcon Glyph="" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>

                <NavigationViewItem Content="Mode conférence" Tag="Conference">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <FontIcon Glyph="" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>

                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Help" Content="Aide" Tag="Aide"/>

                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Admin" Content="Mode instructeur" Tag="Instructeur"/>

            </NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>

        </NavigationView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: to me it looks like the CallSection  page you are displaying and the CallSection are different objects

Comment: If I add a Debug.WriteLine(Numero) in my UpdateEtablissementAppel method, I can see all numbers ... but my textbox doesn't update ...

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `CallSection` and call the `UpdateEtablissementAppel` method of this one. This will obviously not affect the instance that you see on the screen. You need to get a reference to the existing instance and call its `UpdateEtablissementAppel` method. How do this depends on how your UI and XAML is structured. Please post your XAML.

Comment: @mm8 Look at the post above, I just put it up to date

Comment: @mm8 I just added the MainPage xaml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `CallSection` and then call the `UpdateEtablissementAppel` method of this one. This will obviously not affect the instance that you see on the screen. You need to get a reference to the existing instance and call its `UpdateEtablissementAppel` method.

You could use the following helper method to get a reference to the parent `MainPage`:

```
private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

And then cast the `Content` of the "CallsSection" `Frame`:

```
private void UpdateTextBox(string _UpdatePrefix, string _UpdateNumeroDestinataire)
{
    MainPage mainPage = FindParent<MainPage>(this);
    if (mainPage != null)
    {
        CallSection cellSection = mainPage.CallsSection.Content as CallSection;
        if (cellSection != null)
            cellSection.UpdateEtablissementAppel(_UpdatePrefix, _UpdateNumeroDestinataire);
    }
}
```

You also need to make the `Frame` accessible from other classes. You can do this returning a reference to it from a public property of `MainPage.xaml.cs`, or by using the [x:FieldModifier attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-fieldmodifier-attribute) directly in the XAML markup:

```
<Frame x:Name="CallsSection" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: I put UpdatetextBox in my Clavier.xaml.cs or in my MainPage.xaml.cs ?

Comment: @ValentinDubois-Pivot: In Clavier.xaml.cs.

Comment: I have an error : MainPage.CallsSection is inaccessible due to its level of protection

Comment: @ValentinDubois-Pivot: Set the [x:FieldModifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-fieldmodifier-attribute) of the `Frame` to `public` in `MainPage.xaml` or expose the `Frame` using a property in the code-behind. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)